# Select rows based on value in list

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to select all the rows which contain the name 'bil', or 'bob', preferably without writing out each condition (avoiding this: `df2[df2['name']=='bil'|df2['name']=='bob']`). I thought the `in` operator would work here, but it doesnt seem to. Are there any easier ways to do this?

```
d = {'name':['bil','bil','bil','jim'],
     'date': ['2018-02-27 14:55:29', '2018-03-27 15:55:29', '2018-02-28 19:55:29','2018-02-28 19:55:29'], 
     'col2': [3,'', 4,''],
     'col3': [1,2,3,55]
    }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df2[df2['name'] in ['bil','bob']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is it:

```
df2.loc[df2['name'].isin(['bil','bob'])]
```